# Twilio: Problemas con dependencias en Android

Tags: android, gradle, twilio

haciendo una implementación de dos SDK de Twilio:

- Programmable Video
- IP Messaging Client

me encuentro con el problema de que las dependencias de una, me afecta a la otra, o al menos eso creo ya que primero implementé el `IP Messaging Client`y funacionaba sin problemas, y ahora que he agregado la dependencia para `Programmable Video`, y trato de correr el proyecto, me dice que no encuentras 3 de la clases usadas para `IP Messaging Client` en el paquete `com.twilio.common`, pero las de `Programmable Video` si las encuentra. Abajo especifico parte del gradle (Module):

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'
   compile 'com.twilio:ip-messaging-android:0.8.1'
   compile 'com.twilio:conversations-android:0.12.2'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

También las clases con las que tengo el conflicto de `IP Messaging Client` (no están en el paquete, las demás clases si están):

```
import com.twilio.common.TwilioAccessManager;
import com.twilio.common.TwilioAccessManagerFactory;
import com.twilio.common.TwilioAccessManagerListener;
```

Y las clases de `Programmable Video` que estoy usando:

```
import com.twilio.common.AccessManager;
import com.twilio.conversations.IncomingInvite;
import com.twilio.conversations.LogLevel;
import com.twilio.conversations.TwilioConversationsClient;
import com.twilio.conversations.TwilioConversationsException;
```

Noten que la clase `AccessManager` de `Programmable Video` es la misma y está al mismo nivel que la clase `TwilioAccessManager` usada para `IP Messaging Client` las que en teoría hacen lo mismo. Pero las demás clases, no se encuentran.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme con este problema. Saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya un programador de Twilio me respondió por stackoverflow english y me comentó sobre la nueva actualización del SDK de `ip-messaging-android`:

```
compile 'com.twilio:ip-messaging-android:0.9.0'
compile 'com.twilio:conversations-android:0.12.2'
```

Casualmente se publicó esta actualización (que resuelve el problema entre SDK's) un día después de hacer mi pregunta xD.

Referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38615118/twilio-android-dependencies-issue

Comment: Que buena suerte Ernesto :) recuerda marcarla como respuesta aceptada para que futuros lectores encuentren la solución mas rapido

Answer (score 0):

veo que tus dependencia de twilio son de versiones distintas:

```
 compile 'com.twilio:ip-messaging-android:0.8.1'   <--
 compile 'com.twilio:conversations-android:0.12.2' <--
```

proba cambiando la dependencia de conversations a 0.8.1

```
compile 'com.twilio:conversations-android:0.8.1'
```

No estoy 100% seguro pero capaz funcione. saludos!

Comment: Hola! Las versiones son de los respectivos SDK, Al parecer los programadores no se pusieron de acuerdo con el nombre de las clases y estructura del paquete `common`, y al momento de construir el gradle se sustituye el paquete `common` de `ip-messaging` por la de `conversations` ya que figura como la más reciente.